# iOS handle dynamic link while app is inactive

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

My ApplicationDelegate:

```
let customURLScheme = "dlscheme"

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

FIROptions.default().deepLinkURLScheme = self.customURLScheme
FIRApp.configure()

return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: nil, annotation: [:])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let dynamicLink = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()?.dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
    if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
        let message = generateDynamicLinkMessage(dynamicLink)
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            showDeepLinkAlertView(withMessage: message)
        }
        return true
    }
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        showDeepLinkAlertView(withMessage: "openURL:\n\(url)")
    } else {
    }
    return false
}
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let dynamicLinks = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
        return false
    }
    let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
        let message = self.generateDynamicLinkMessage(dynamiclink!)
        self.showDeepLinkAlertView(withMessage: message)
    }
    return handled
}

func generateDynamicLinkMessage(_ dynamicLink: FIRDynamicLink) -> String {
    let matchConfidence: String
    if dynamicLink.matchConfidence == .weak {
        matchConfidence = "Weak"
    } else {
        matchConfidence = "Strong"
    }
    let message = "App URL: \(dynamicLink.url)\nMatch Confidence: \(matchConfidence)\n"
    return message
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func showDeepLinkAlertView(withMessage message: String) {
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        print("OK")
    }

    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Deep-link Data", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is my code. I am working with firebase dynamic link, and implemented it like this tutorial:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios

And this sample:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/dynamiclinks/DynamicLinksExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift

Its working well when my app is in background. Open the app and show alert with url when I tap on dynamic link.

But in the case my app is inactive (not running), it not working. Just open the app and do nothing.

And my question: How can i handle dynamic link while app is inactive?
 Sorry about my english

Comment: Did you managed to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

You can handle it in such way:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseDynamicLinks

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // ... your other code here

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let activityKey = NSString(string: "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey")
    if let userActivityDict = launchOptions?[.userActivityDictionary] as? [NSObject : AnyObject], let userActivity = userActivityDict[activityKey] as? NSUserActivity, let webPageUrl = userActivity.webpageURL {
        
        DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(webPageUrl) { (dynamiclink, error) in
            
            // do some stuff with dynamiclink
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: what's the code for `// do some stuff with dynamiclink` ?

Comment: @TomSawyer depends on your needs. In my way: `if let url = dynamiclink?.url, let contenttype = url["contenttype"], let contentid = url["contentid"] { ... }`

Comment: i don't use Firebase, but calling openURL from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have do like this...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{

 if let option = launchOptions
    {
        if option.keys.contains(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary)
        {
            if let userActivityDict = option[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [AnyHashable:Any]
            {
                if userActivityDict.keys.contains(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityType)
                {
                    if let userActivity = userActivityDict["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {

                        if let webpageURL = userActivity.webpageURL
                        {
                            // Write your code here.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That 6-level (!!) conditional check you have can be expressed with a single-level `if` or `guard`. 17 lines into 5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when `application(_:open:options:)` wasn't called when the app was in background. The Firebase SDK swizzles methods and that was the reason.

I solved this problem by setting `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO` in `Info.plist`

For more detailed information on how it works and what it affects you can read here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in